# My action bar appears as a blank rectangle with no buttons. Why?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an action bar for my app, but when I run the app in my emulator, it just appears as a solid color rectangle with nothing in it.

Can anyone help me with why?

Toolbar in main screen XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Toolbar code in /res/menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_edit_foreground"
        android:title="Edit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete_foreground"
        android:title="Delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Code in main activity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        Toolbar toolbarMain;

        toolbarMain = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

This isn't all the code, of course, but it's everything that deals with the toolbar.

Comment: Is the `<Toolbar>` directly in the `activity_main_screen` layout? Or is it possibly in another `<include>`d layout?

Comment: It's inside activity_main_screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your theme to `NoActionBar` since you are adding the `Toolbar` into the XML?

Either in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

or in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was being stupid and resetting the content view to my activity_main_screen in my onResume method.